# Migration from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5: sessionFactory (MetadataImplementor) is null

Tags: metadata, tomcat8, spring-4, sessionfactory, hibernate-5.x

```
    public class EntityMetaData implements SessionFactoryBuilderFactory {

    // private static final ThreadLocal<MetadataImplementor> meta = new ThreadLocal<>();  // previously used, but did not work, so used HashMap

      private static final Map<String, MetadataImplementor> meta = new HashMap<>();
      private static final String METADATAKEY = "M";

    @Override
    public SessionFactoryBuilder getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImplementor metadata, SessionFactoryBuilderImplementor defaultBuilder) {
    //  meta.set(metadata);

        meta.put(METADATAKEY, metadata);
        return defaultBuilder;  
    }

    public static MetadataImplementor getMeta() {
//        return meta.get();

        return meta.get(METADATAKEY);
    }
}
```

The above code works in tomcat 8 of Local environment, but in tomcat 8 of production environment not working as `getMeta()` method returns null.

In Local Environment, `getSessionFactoryBuilder` method is called while server is getting started so that it is working in Local, but in Production environment `getSessionFactoryBuilder` method not called thus `getMeta()` returns `null`.

Any help could be appreciated.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please anyone can help me on this..Its a `production` issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

It's a compiling problem. `META-INF` folder is not there in `classes` folder, so `metadata` is not loading (means `getSessionFactoryBuilder` method not getting called) during server startup. In Local environment, `META-INF` is there in `classes` folder..But in Production environment it is not available, so tried to compile `META-INF` and available in `classes` folder, then after it's working.